# iPhone 4 doesn't show up on devices list

Tags: iphone, icloud, apple-id

According to this page: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT205064
and this:

> To see any devices running iOS 7 or OS X Mavericks or earlier, you need to be signed in to iCloud on the device and you need Find My iPhone turned on.

I need to be signed into iCloud and have Find my iPhone turned on. I have done both of those things and Find my iPhone locates it as well, but the device doesn't show up on my iCloud or AppleID account even though it backs up on iCloud.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Your question isn't clear - where are you expecting the device to show up?

Comment: I expected it to show up on iCloud.com & appleID.apple.com but it appeared in neither

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and in iCloud.com now it appears to be requiring iOS 8 or higher.

Comment: This is it most likely, but what an oversight on Apple's part. Does it mean that no one with an iPhone older than 4S can use iCloud anymore?

Comment: It certain seems an oversight to those of us who are satisfied with the 4S, but it is Apple's current philosophy that support for older hardware is counter productive (think $$$)

Answer (score 0):

Check and see what your iPhone 4's iCloud email address is:

Settings --> iCloud --> Your Name --> Your email.

Make sure the email address is the same as the one you are using.